# SQL Server - Forcing a Row To display In A ResultSet Where No Values Exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, coalesce

I'm trying to find a way of forcing a row to display in my output resultset even when no value is found. I may be on the right lines using `COALESCE`, but I can't figure out where it needs to be in my query.

I've tried a couple of places, but with no success. My code so far is below.

So in the case of the code below it would return a row for a subject where student(s) with results have SEND set to `'Y'`, but then no row is displayed where there are no student with results in the subject who have SEND set to `'N'`. However, I would like a row to display for formatting purposes, so the output resultset is always the same size whether there are SEND students who have results or not.

```
DECLARE @AcademicYear varchar(9) = '2017/2018',
        @Collection varchar(50) = 'Autumn';

SELECT
 Year,
 CASE Subject
    WHEN 'English' THEN 1
    WHEN 'English Language' THEN 2
    WHEN 'English Literature' THEN 3
    WHEN 'Maths' THEN 4
    WHEN 'Science' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Additional Science' THEN 6
    WHEN 'Biology' THEN 7
    WHEN 'Chemistry' THEN 8
    WHEN 'Physics' THEN 9
    WHEN 'Arabic' THEN 10
    WHEN 'Dutch' THEN 11
    WHEN 'French' THEN 12
    WHEN 'Russian' THEN 13
    WHEN 'Spanish' THEN 14
    WHEN 'Urdu' THEN 15
    ELSE 16
  END AS SubjectSort,

  Subject,
  5 AS GroupSort, Class, Teacher,
  'SEND (' + CAST(COUNT(g1.Points) AS varchar) + ')' AS 'Group',

  COALESCE(Count(1),0)  AS 'No. Girls',

  --4+
  SUM(CASE
    WHEN g1.Points >= 4 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS 'No. 4+/A*-C',
  CAST(SUM(CASE
    WHEN g1.Points >= 4 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS decimal) / COUNT(g2.Points) AS '% 4+/A*-C',
  --5+
  SUM(CASE
    WHEN g1.Points >= 5 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS 'No. 5+/A*-B',
  CAST(SUM(CASE
    WHEN g1.Points >= 5 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS decimal) / COUNT(g1.Points) AS '% 5+/A*-B',
  --7+
  SUM(CASE
    WHEN g1.Points >= 7 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS 'No. 7+/A*-A',
  CAST(SUM(CASE
    WHEN g1.Points >= 7 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS decimal) / COUNT(g1.Points) AS '% 7+/A*-A'

FROM Results r
JOIN Grades g1
  ON r.Result = g1.Grade
INNER JOIN Grades g2
  ON r.Target = g2.Grade
INNER JOIN Grades g3
  ON r.Prediction = g3.Grade 
INNER JOIN Grades g4 
  ON r.Mock = g4.Grade 
INNER JOIN students s
  ON r.UPN = s.UPN

WHERE r.AcademicYear = @AcademicYear
AND s.AcademicYear = @AcademicYear
AND r.Collection = @Collection
AND COALESCE(SEND,'') = 'Y'

GROUP BY Year, Class, Teacher,
         Subject

Order by SubjectSort, Subject, Class, Teacher, GroupSort
```

Comment: You can union your query with a row of nulls.

Comment: @RigertaDemiri would this not result in two rows where there are results in the resultset? I'm looking for the null values or zero values where there are no results in the resultset.

Comment: `UNION ALL` with similar query but `AND COALESCE(SEND,'') = 'N'` or remove `AND COALESCE(SEND,'') = 'Y'` and add column `COALESCE(SEND,'') as [Send]`

Comment: I don't really understand your requirement, but using `coalesce` in a `where` clause just kills performance unnecessarily. If you simply use `SEND = 'Y'`, NULL values are already filtered out. Perhaps you'll get a better answer if you can explain what `SEND = 'Y'` actually means.

Comment: @HoneyBadger I'm not trying to filter them out, I'm trying to include them. There is a subject called Art. No students with SEND as Y study it, so therefore there is no row in the resultset where SEND='Y', but I would like there to be a row in the Resultset that displays the Subject and then either NULLs or zeros where the values would be.

Comment: In that case you should join a `Subject` table, which contains all subjects. Than you can move the `send` filter to a join condition

Comment: @HoneyBadger my results table already contains all of the subjects, but I'm already joining my results table to the students table by UPN using an inner join (the student table contains the SEND column). would I be able to join again based on the subject or am I better off creating a brand new table and joining to that?

Comment: You should make all your inner join left joins, and move the where clause to the join conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
declare @t table(name varchar(100));
insert into @t values ('Paul'), ('Jane'), ('Mary');

declare @param varchar(100) = 'Sean'--'Paul';

select *
from @t
where name = @param

union all

select 'no name found'
where not exists(select *
                from @t
                where name = @param
                 );
```

Uncomment an existing name and see how rows from your table are returned; if there is no row matching your parameter, 'no name found' will be returned.